# how can i select serial raws on condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, conditional-statements

i have below data frame...
i want select serial 12 points from b>1000 condition everyday

```
Date        Time     a      b    c
2018-01-09  5:15:00 20.55   0   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:30:00 20.57   10000   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:45:00 20.33   0   -3.44
2018-01-09  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
2018-01-09  8:15:00 23.25   15438   -3.48
2018-01-09  8:30:00 23.44   16218   -3.65
2018-01-09  8:45:00 23.65   14666   -3.14
2018-01-09  9:00:00 24.01   14686   -3.1
.....
```

must be serial 12 points from b>1000 condition
result shoulbe

```
  Date        Time     a      b    c
    2018-01-09  5:30:00 20.57   10000   -3.07
    2018-01-09  5:45:00 20.33   0   -3.44
    2018-01-09  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
    2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
    2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
    2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
    2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
    2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
    2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
    2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
    2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
    2018-01-09  8:15:00 23.25   15438   -3.48
    .....
```

how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then select first `12` rows per day by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html).

Condition select all rows per days after first value `b > 1000`.

```
#changed data with multiple days for better test
print (df)
          Date     Time      a      b     c
0   2018-01-09  5:15:00  20.55      0 -3.07
1   2018-01-09  5:30:00  20.57  10000 -3.07
2   2018-01-09  5:45:00  20.33      0 -3.44
3   2018-01-09  6:00:00  20.31      0 -2.95
4   2018-01-09  6:15:00  20.76  26738 -2.88
5   2018-01-09  6:30:00  21.40  22462 -2.77
6   2018-01-09  6:45:00  21.84  20033 -3.00
7   2018-02-09  7:00:00  22.17    100 -3.28
8   2018-02-09  7:15:00  22.38      0 -2.82
9   2018-02-09  7:30:00  22.75  18254 -3.14
10  2018-02-09  7:45:00  22.93      0 -3.22
11  2018-02-09  8:00:00  23.13      0 -3.27
12  2018-02-09  8:15:00  23.25  15438 -3.48
13  2018-02-09  8:30:00  23.44  16218 -3.65
14  2018-02-09  8:45:00  23.65  14666 -3.14
15  2018-02-09  9:00:00  24.01  14686 -3.10
```

---

```
m = df['b'].gt(1000).groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0)).cumsum().gt(0)
df = df[m].groupby('Date').head(12)
print (df)
          Date     Time      a      b     c
1   2018-01-09  5:30:00  20.57  10000 -3.07
2   2018-01-09  5:45:00  20.33      0 -3.44
3   2018-01-09  6:00:00  20.31      0 -2.95
4   2018-01-09  6:15:00  20.76  26738 -2.88
5   2018-01-09  6:30:00  21.40  22462 -2.77
6   2018-01-09  6:45:00  21.84  20033 -3.00
9   2018-02-09  7:30:00  22.75  18254 -3.14
10  2018-02-09  7:45:00  22.93      0 -3.22
11  2018-02-09  8:00:00  23.13      0 -3.27
12  2018-02-09  8:15:00  23.25  15438 -3.48
13  2018-02-09  8:30:00  23.44  16218 -3.65
14  2018-02-09  8:45:00  23.65  14666 -3.14
15  2018-02-09  9:00:00  24.01  14686 -3.10
```

Comment: it's not working ! because i need once b>1000, then get 12 serial point regardless of b value !

Comment: exactly, need first 12 serial rows regardless of b value

Comment: still have problem...in your answer dataframe,0 row b value is 10000, then i need select serial rows from 0 row regradless of b value (1,2,3 rows b values are 0 but wanna select serial 12 rows ..)

Comment: Not sure if understand. My solution filter by chunks - data per each day are splitted by `b>1000` and then by `groupby.head(12)` are selected first 12 consecutive rows by `b>1000`. Is it right?

Comment: i changed my question .. added my wanna results .. plz check.. after b>1000 condtion is satisfied.. b=0 is also okay.. including b=0 values .. wanna select 12 points from the first b>1000 condition

Comment: plz check again... in running "m =df['b'].gt(1000).groupby(df['Date']).cumsum().gt(0)" have Date error!   Date, Time is multi index .. i don't know exacltly..

Comment: solved !  changed to "m = df_per_wday['airflow'].gt(1000).groupby(df_per_wday.index.get_level_values(0)).cumsum().gt(0)" thanks again!